# Postmessage LParam truncation

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, postmessage

My app has a worker thread, and I use PostMessage to send a string to the main thread. For 1 message, the string is truncated when it gets to the message handler in the main thread.

The string is constructed in the worker thread from a string of raw data that is like this. It ends at the last '20'.

'01010000000030000102000008850008855343414E204544474520000000000000000000'

Decoded into the string I want to send it looks like this, which is correct:

'0100 0.50000   LSB0288.588.5SCAN EDGE '

The code that creates the 'SCAN EDGE ' portion and posts it is:
tmp and s_out are strings

```
x := 35;
for i := 1 to 10 do
begin
  tmp := '$' + copy(s,x,2);
  TryStrToInt(tmp,dec);
  s_out := s_out + chr(dec);
  x := x + 2;
end;
PostMessage(MainHandle,UM_CLONE, UM_756, Integer(PChar(s_out)));
```

The message handler in the main thread is:
i is a string

```
i := pChar(msg.LParam);
```

when it gets to the main thread i looks like this in the debugger:

'0100 0.50000   LSB0288.588.5SCAN EDG'#0

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are posting the contents of a `String` variable that is local to the thread procedure that is calling `PostMessage()`.  If the `String` goes out of scope and gets freed before the main thread processes the posted message, the memory will be garbage.

You need to either:

1) use `SendMessage()` instead of `PostMessage()` so the `String` stays in scope until the message handler exits:

```
SendMessage(MainHandle, UM_CLONE, UM_756, LPARAM(PChar(s_out)));
```

2) dynamically allocate a `String` in memory, fill it as needed, post it, and then let the main message handler free it when it is done copying it:

```
var
  s_out: PString;

New(s_out);
...
s_out^ := s_out^ + chr(dec);
...
if not PostMessage(MainHandle, UM_CLONE, UM_756, LPARAM(s_out)) then
  Dispose(s_out);
```

.

```
var
  ps: PString;
  i: String;

ps := PString(msg.LParam);
i := ps^;
Dispose(ps);
```

PS: notice I also changed your `Integer()` cast to `LPARAM()`.  This is very important if you ever upgrade to Delphi XE2 or later.  `PostMessage()` and `SendMessage()` use `LPARAM`, not `Integer`.  You can get away with it in Delphi 7 because `LPARAM` is an alias for `Integer` in that version, but that is not the case anymore in modern Delphi versions.  `LPARAM` is an alias for `NativeUInt` now.  `LPARAM` has always been an unsinged type in the Win32 API, Delphi just got it wrong in the early versions, but Embarcadero has really been pushing for type-correctness in the RTL/VCL since adding support for 64-bit and cross-platform development.  If you don't match the right data types correctly, you can cause range checks errors and such at runtime.

Comment: It will work only within the same process. For interprocess communication using messages, use WM_COPY, which will marshall the content as expected.

Comment: You are thinking of `WM_COPYDATA` instead.