# Is the TForm.Handle thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, postmessage

I routinely pass the main form handle to other threads so that they can post messages back to the main thread. I saw that on Sept 28, 2013, Remy Lebeau stated:

> ...the TWinControl.Handle property is not thread-safe, either. You
>   should use the TApplication.Handle property instead, or use
>   AllocateHWnd() to create your own window.

in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19063457/960757) to a question about passing strings.

How is the handle property not safe? Does it change during the life of the program?

Comment: Yes, it can change.  The window can be re-created.  If it is, the old handle will cease to be valid.

Comment: [AllocateHWnd is not Thread-Safe](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007/06/allocatehwnd-is-not-thread-safe.html) under some circumstances. [QC report for that issue](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=47559)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar `AllocateHwnd` cannot be safely called from a thread - that doesn't mean you can't call it on the main thread and pass the handle it returns to a worker thread.  That's fine.

Comment: @J... I know..., I have updated my comment after I have realized that I haven't expressed myself clearly.

Answer (score 9):

> How is the `Handle` property not safe?

When you access the `Handle` property, if the window handle has not been created, then it is created on demand. If you access the `Handle` property from a thread other than the GUI thread, then this means you create the window on the wrong thread.

> Does it change during the life of the program?

Yes, the window handle can change if the window is re-created.

> I routinely pass the main form handle to other threads so that they can post messages back to the main thread.

In this case, you are probably not accessing the `Handle` property away from the main thread. It sounds like (although I cannot see your code) you are accessing `Handle` on the main thread and passing that value to the other thread.

However, window recreation is the problem for you. Since your window is subject to recreation, you simply cannot rely on that handle outliving your thread. Whether or not your window will ever be recreated is hard to predict. The VCL does not perform recreation lightly. However, in my view it is far better to be safe than sorry. So, use `AllocateHWnd` and take control of the lifetime of this window.

Comment: Worth noting that window recreation can be triggered by something as simple as changing a Form property that can only be set with a call to `CreateWindowEx`.

Comment: @J...: On the other hand, many window properties that *can* be updated dynamically without recreation are *not* updated accordingly by the VCL. It usually just forces a full recreate and applies the latest property values in overridden `CreateParams()` and `CreateWnd()` methods.

Comment: Most of those cases are because not all versions of Windows allows certain style changes without recreating the window handle. If there are some which don't require handle recreation on the versions of Windows we now support (XP is now off the supported versions list), then report it in our Quality Portal (http://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: What about using the TApplication.Handle? Wouldn't that be guaranteed to be valid for the lifetime of the application?

Comment: You could do that. But then you'd have to hook its window procedure. Perfectly possible, use `TApplication.HookMainWindow`. What exactly is wrong with using `AllocateHWnd`?

Comment: Just shy because of the "AllocateHWnd is not Thread-Safe" caution above. After reading it, I think AllocateHWnd will work fine for me.