# delphi thread waitfor infinite (never terminate)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm waiting for the Thread to finish, but without success, it gets stuck in the WaitFor () method; and does not return, standing there indefinitely.

```
procedure TForm1.btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
```

Can anyone help me?

I am using Delphi Berlin 10.1 Update 2, running on a Windows 10 64-bit version 1709 16299.64

follows the code:

```
unit untPrincipal;

interface

uses
   Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
   Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

const
   WM_TEST_SERVICE = WM_APP + 1;

type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
      btnStart: TButton;
      mmoOutput: TMemo;
      btnStop: TButton;
      procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
      procedure btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
   private
      { Private declarations }
      threadService: TThread;
      procedure OnThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
      procedure WMTestService(var msg: TMessage); message WM_TEST_SERVICE;
   public
      { Public declarations }
   end;

   IThreadInfo = interface
      ['{B179712B-8B14-4D54-86DA-AB22227DBCAA}']
      function IsRunning: Boolean;
   end;

   IService = interface
      ['{30934A11-1FB9-46CB-8403-F66317B50199}']
      procedure ServiceCreate();
      procedure ServiceStart(const info: IThreadInfo);
   end;

   TMyService = class(TInterfacedObject, IService)
   private
      handle: THandle;
   public
      constructor Create(const handle: THandle);
      procedure ServiceCreate;
      procedure ServiceStart(const info: IThreadInfo);
   end;

   TThreadService = class(TThread)
   private
      service: IService;
   protected
      procedure Execute; override;
   public
      constructor Create(const service: IService);
   end;

   TThreadInfo = class(TInterfacedObject, IThreadInfo)
   private
      thread: TThread;
   public
      constructor Create(const thread: TThread);
      function IsRunning: Boolean;
   end;

   TThreadPost = class(TThread)
   private
      handle: THandle;
      info: IThreadInfo;
   protected
      procedure Execute; override;
   public
      constructor Create(const handle: THandle; const info: IThreadInfo);
   end;

var
   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   service: IService;
begin
   service := TMyService.Create(Self.handle);
   threadService := TThreadService.Create(service);
   threadService.OnTerminate := OnThreadTerminate;
   threadService.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if Assigned(threadService) then
   begin
      try
         threadService.Terminate;
         threadService.WaitFor;
      finally
         if Assigned(threadService) then
            FreeAndNil(threadService);
      end;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   mmoOutput.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(Now()) + ' - procedure TForm1.OnThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);');
end;

procedure TForm1.WMTestService(var msg: TMessage);
begin
   mmoOutput.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(Now()) + ' - Service');
end;

{ TMyService }

constructor TMyService.Create(const handle: THandle);
begin
   inherited Create();
   Self.handle := handle;
end;

procedure TMyService.ServiceCreate;
begin
   PostMessage(handle, WM_TEST_SERVICE, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMyService.ServiceStart(const info: IThreadInfo);
var
   thread: TThreadPost;
begin
   while info.IsRunning do
   begin
      thread := TThreadPost.Create(handle, info);
      try
         thread.Start;
         thread.WaitFor;
         ShowMessage('Never Execute');
      finally
         thread.Free;
      end;
   end;
end;

{ TThreadService }

constructor TThreadService.Create(const service: IService);
begin
   inherited Create(True);
   Self.service := service;
end;

procedure TThreadService.Execute;
begin
   service.ServiceCreate;
   service.ServiceStart(TThreadInfo.Create(Self) as IThreadInfo);
end;

{ TThreadInfo }

constructor TThreadInfo.Create(const thread: TThread);
begin
   inherited Create();
   Self.thread := thread;
end;

function TThreadInfo.IsRunning: Boolean;
begin
   Result := not thread.CheckTerminated;
end;

{ TThreadPost }

constructor TThreadPost.Create(const handle: THandle; const info: IThreadInfo);
begin
   inherited Create(True);
   Self.handle := handle;
   Self.info := info;
end;

procedure TThreadPost.Execute;
begin
   while info.IsRunning do
   begin
      PostMessage(handle, WM_TEST_SERVICE, 0, 0);
      Sleep(1000);
   end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why would you call that just after starting the thread? Why have a thread at all in that case? Why does the thread never check for `Terminated`?

Comment: this code is just to show a problem I'm having in a larger system, where there are several IService running, and each has its own thread, when I finalize the system (Windows Service in case) I have to end all threads, wait the same are finished and other operations are performed, the problem is when I have to finish. each IService is implemented differently and in some cases, it has more Threads running inside them, and that's where I found the problem

Comment: @JerryDodge,You said that the WaitFor () method is unnecessary, but how do I wait for Thread to end at this point? thank you

Comment: The main form handle could be recreated any time. Use a handle of your own to post messages. See [Is the TForm.Handle thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460970/is-the-tform-handle-thread-safe). Calling `ShowMessage` from a thread is wrong, since vcl is not thread safe.

Comment: @LURD Thanks for your comment, but ShowMessage never runs, because the code gets stopped in the WaitFor () method. on the Handle, this has only ever been a problem with Threads and PostMessage, so much so that while the code is stopped in the WaitFor () method, PostMessage continues to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling:

```
function TThreadInfo.IsRunning: Boolean;
begin
   Result := not thread.CheckTerminated;
end;
```

from `TThreadPost.Execute`, which tries to check if `thread` instance is terminated or not.

The problem is that the call to [CheckTerminated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.CheckTerminated) uses the current thread terminated status, not the `thread` instance.
(Think what would have happened if the `thread` instance was terminated and freed at the time when `thread.CheckTerminated` was called, if that was possible).

The result is that `IsRunning` never will be false, and you will have an endless loop.
You will have to redesign how to stop the threads in a safe manner.

Comment: I was about to post my answer when I saw yours. it took me 10 min to decide whether I should post or not.

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout, it's ok. At the moment I cannot recommend a good solution, other than a redesign. It is not a good solution to nest threads and complex logic together like this. I always try to separate responsibilities in a producer/consumer scheme, and logic/data should only be passed, not shared.

Comment: Yes, a redesign would be the way to go here . I think my answer covers why the deadlock happened. I will leave the solution to you. :)

Comment: @LURD thanks, simply changing the check by a control variable, the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

before we start anything here please next time start the names of fields in your class with an 'F'.

Let's go through your code step by step starting with the first user action

```
procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
```

1. `service := TMyService.Create(Self.handle);`

you create an instance of `TMyService` and assign `TForm.Handle` to the field `handle` (which you should name `FHandle`).

2. `threadService := TThreadService.Create(service);`

you create a suspended instance of `TThread` and assign `service` to its private field `service` (again you should name it `FService`and you do not need to use self)

one thing is that the reference this time is kept unlike the first line where the reference dies/lost at end of scope.

3. `threadService.OnTerminate := OnThreadTerminate;`

assign Onterminate event handler.

Onterminate uses synchronize() internally so this could be the cause of the deadlock. (<--- future bug prone one)

4. `threadService.Start;`

you start the suspended `threadService`.

at this point now you have two threads running the MainThread and the threadService (MyService runs in the context of the MainThread).

the MainThread is Idle waiting for more user action or handling other messages
(i.e: repaint, resize, move form....etc).

threadService is running its execute method.

now let's follow what is the `TThreadService.Execute;` doing

1. `service.ServiceCreate;`

here you post a message to `handle == TForm.Handle` (<--future bug prone two)

2. `service.ServiceStart(TThreadInfo.Create(Self) as IThreadInfo);`

   2.1 `while info.IsRunning do`

your problem is here because `info.IsRunning` checks for the terminate flag in the current thread (internally otherwise an exception will be raised) which is `threadService` (<-- future error prone three).

```
 2.2 **the catastrophe code**

    begin
      thread := TThreadPost.Create(handle, info);
      try
         thread.Start;
         thread.WaitFor;
         ShowMessage('Never Execute');
      finally
         thread.Free;
      end;
   end;
```

here you create `TThreadPost` which is another thread and start it. then you call `waitfor` on it locking `TThreadService`. 
 so now you have three threads running:  the MainThread (Idle), `threadService` (deadlocked) and a `TThreadPost` (loose).

In the `TThreadPost` execute method there is another `while info.IsRunning do`

checking for the terminate flag but it is the `TThreadPost`'s one not the `threadService` one.

so when the user hits Stop button the `waitfor` call in the MainThread is waiting on a deadlocked thread.

as a solution you do as LU RD said (I was writing my answer when he posted his).